# Reviews audits: what criteria behind suspend

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-audits, review-suspension

I have a question about criteria followed to suspend ability to review of a user.

In this weeks I reviewed hundreds of post, "first question", "edit reviews" etc. Sometime I made some error but it seems that weight of gravity of these errors (sometimes discussable...) is exaggerated.

10 days ago, after 50 edit reviews I was suspended for a week after one error. Today, after almost 100 edit reviews, after another one, I am suspended for a month.....

It seems that 100 correct reviews and dozens of passed tests are irrelevant in comparison to sporadic mistakes... What are these criteria?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10062455 is a machine-generated non-sensical edit. Suggested edit audit are extremely easy to detect if you pay even a bit of attention, so failing such audit indicates that you should slow down and take a closer look.

Comment: Ok, I can agree with you.... but I repeat... it seems that a single error is 100 times more important that other dozens of right reviews. In other words, I think it's too severe this criteria. One week could be enough, a month... I sincerely think that is exxagerated, also because suspendation is for all types of reviews, not only for the "incriminated" one.

Comment: If you're not able to catch suggested edit audits, you're not paying --enough-- **any** attention. If you're not paying attention in one queue, chances are you don't in others.

Comment: And you don't get suspended for a week after one error. You get suspended for a week having previously been suspended for two days after two errors. I doubt you've got 100 *correct reviews* also, you've barely done more than 100 in the suggested edit queue.

Comment: I have more 300 hundreds review in "triage", almost 250 in "first post", about 100 in "suggested edit". I am not a true beginner. Ok, error is a human thing, but according to you, we are speaking about 3-4 errors on 400 hundreds of right reviews.....

Comment: 3-4 **caught** errors, on 400 *reviews*. How many of those reviews were actually audits and certifiably correct, vs where you just weren't being audits and (potentially) caused harm to the site.

Comment: These edits are just some that should not have been approved: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9913720 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10062251 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10062438 . Take a little more time to look over your recent review history and examine the reviews where you differed from other reviewers.

Comment: I don't want to continue this topic anymore.... but regarding your last links, I surely agree that first one was a my fault, but sincerely I disagree with the second one. Ok, could be supeflous but surely is disputable that proposed edit could be completely unuseful. It added enphasis to some words and more clarity on links content. Effectively, 3 other people agreed with me, ad only two disagree...... I kow that this changes nothing, but just to point out

Comment: It is [generally agreed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) that inline code tags should **not** be used for emphasis.

Comment: I believe the whole process and the criteria are not fair. The system has to consider more sensible factors to examine the users. 4 arguable post or maybe mistakes have banned me for a year and so!!!! My review privileges are suspended until Jun 27 '22 by 4 errors that is ridiculous. In my opinion, the system needs to be revised in order to compute the number of failures in the total number of revisions. 4 errors in 600 or more reviews is not the end of the world!

Answer (score 8):

Every time you fail an audit, you get *less* room for error, and failing them will result in more and more severe consequences.

Since you've been review banned a couple of times already, the system will intervene after just *one* failed audit.

Comment: And the thing is always irrecuperable? In this way, concept of "good conduct" to have "reduction of sentences" is not applied

Comment: @Luca If you stop failing audits, you'll stop getting automatically banned for failing audits.

Comment: This approach does not help users to have desire in review contributions. It's a "punishment" method

Comment: @Luca No, it's not a punishment method. It's to give you time to think about what you've done wrong (which you seem reluctant to acknowledge) and in the mean time prevent your lack of paying attention causing harm to the site. What improvement do you think [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10062455) actually made to that post?

Comment: In one minute you clicked "Approve" on **seven** suggested edit reviews. You are **clearly** not taking the time to actually review these edits properly. If all you want is a little gold sticker, hack it in yourself with a userscript, don't make the Internet a worse place.

Comment: Time to approve it's not an undisputable method to judge. I think that you can agree with me about those reviews as correct. They were simple suggested edits, simple to understand and approve. In specific case of error cited, I'm not discusing about possibility that it's effectively a my fault (It is!), I'm discussing only on severity of ban. that's all.

Comment: @LucaDetomi: You've gotten review banned _multiple times_ already. Like I answered, every time you get banned, the consequences of failing an audit get _more severe_. Yes, a months _is_ long, but to be blunt, that's all your own doing.